# Python datetime that fall between a datetime range

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I am trying to find out how long a vehicle parks at an area with an enforced time range after a max time is given. 
Ex:

```
area enforced: 2:00 pm to 6:00 pm

max time a vehicle can park: 2 hours

vehicle parked duration: 2880 minutes (2 days)

duration parked after max time: 240 minutes (4 hours)
```

I have two CSV dataframes that are being read with pandas:

```
vehicle_df
```

[image]

```
enforced_area_df
```

[image]

Ultimately I don't know how to check when the start and end time of the parked vehicle fall with in the enforce time range of the enforced area. Does anyone have some libraries that would be helpful and some suggestions to give.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can easily compare datetime instances as you would with numbers. You just need to feed the csv data into datetime objects and compare them. Have a look at pandas to load csv into dataframes. You can also use timedelta objects to compute time  intervals...

Comment: It would be useful to post a part of your data.

Comment: As a tip, when you read in the csv file, use the attribute parse_dates like df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=['start_park_time','end_park_time']) to turn these columns into datetime objects.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions I'll look into it.
@joaoavf apologies, please see the edits I've made.

Comment: I have updated the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something good to do is to read columns `Parked from` and `Parked to` as `datetime`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

vehicle_df = pd.read_csv('vehicle.csv', parse_dates=[2,3])
```

Loading `enforced_area_df`:

```
enforced_area_df = pd.read_csv('enforced_area.csv')
```

Then you need to do something like this to merge the DataFrames:

```
df = vehicle_df.merge(enforced_area_df,on='Zone')
```

You need to get the hours from the `Enforced Time` field:

```
df['Start Enforce'] = df['Enforced Time'].str.split().str[0].str.split(':').str[0].astype(int)
df['Finish Enforce'] = df['Enforced Time'].str.split().str[-1].str.split(':').str[0].astype(int)
```

Then you might do something like this:

```
def check_time(df_line):
    dt_range = pd.date_range(start = df_line['Parked from'], end=df_line['Parked to'], freq='1Min')
    return np.sum((dt_range.hour >= df_line['Start Enforce']) & (dt_range.hour < df_line['Finish Enforce']))


df['Minutes While Enforced'] = df.apply(check_time, axis=1)
```

Not sure on exactly what you are trying to build, but if you tinker around with this code you will be able to do a lot, as there are a lot of important funcionalities in pandas used in there.

And most importantly, it shows how to check when the start and end time of the parked vehicle fall within the enforce time range (and for how long).

Comment: thank you so much, this was exactly what I was trying to achieve, I wasn't quite sure how to word the problem though.